# How to sort Google Drive search results by title?

Tags: search, sorting, filenames, google-drive

I find Google Drive very convenient as an online notebook to store my diary and records, that I can access anytime, anywhere.

Now when I want to search for a particular string of text, the only options are to sort by relevance and date modified, both not very helpful.

I would like to sort the search results by title (filename).

So far I found that the idea has been suggested but not [implemented](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!searchin/drive/sort$20search$20results$20by$20title/drive/Z-z0uoYpg1o/LVZMz_kc7dUJ):

Is there something that a normal user can do? Like installing some App or Add-on?

Answer (score 1):

If you're viewing your documents in a grid
On your pc, visit force.Google.Com.
In the top proper, click on the title of the contemporary kind, like "Name" or "Last modified."
Click on the kind of sorting you need.
To opposite the order, click the up arrow or down arrow .

Comment: domain force.google.com can't be reached: "This site can’t be reached
Check if there is a typo in force.google.com.
If spelling is correct, try running Windows Network Diagnostics.
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN"